# On MacOSX/PPC, suggestions on how to catch KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000

Tags: macos, exception, crash, powerpc

This is a real time MMO client, at some random point it will crash with a jump to 0, and the stack frame is unreadable. The crash reporter (and GDB) will report thread 0 crashed:

```
XC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
```

and

```
srr0=lr=exception address=0
```

How can I catch where this error occurs?

Comment: Could you post the result of the gdb command `info registers` - there might be some useful info in there.

Answer (score 0):

If your stack pointer (`r1`) and link register are trashed then it's not looking good. However, it's possible that some other registers may still have the value of a frame pointer in them - for example non-leaf functions often seen to move the address to they return to to/from the stack via `r0`.

Other than that there's a couple of tricks you could pull - assuming that there is nothing mapped in the processes' address space at address `0x0` (which appears to be the case from the `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error) you could write a simple preload library which mapped page zero; which would allow you to add a breakpoint at `0x0`; which may give you more info on what's going on.